# Uniform continuity of $f(x)=x^{2/3}\log x$ on $[0, \infty)$

Tags: uniform-continuity

Let $f$ be a real valued function on $[0,\infty)$ defined by

$$f(x)= \begin{cases}
x^{{2}/{3}}\log x & \text{ if } x>0 \\ 
0 & \text{ if } x= 0
\end{cases}$$

Then which of the following is true?

A. $f$ is discontinuous at $x=0$.

B. $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$, but not uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$.

C. $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$.

D. $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$, but uniformly continuous on $[1,\infty)$.

I could see that $f(x)=x^{\frac{2}{3}}\log x$ is continous at $x=0$

But for uniform continuity I thought boundedness of derivative would help

But I found $f'(x)=\frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}\log x + x^{-\frac{1}{3}}$

This $f'(x)$ is not bounded so i can not say any thing about uniform contunuity.

Please help me to clear this.

Thank you :)

P.S : This was already asked before ([Uniform continuity of $f(x)=x^{\frac{2}{3}}\log x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599413/uniform-continuity-of-fx-x-frac23-log-x#comment1269069_599413)by) some other person but it was not having enough details so it got closed. I tried to edit that question but someone said I should not edit OP to add more details. I was afraid that may be against the rules of MSE. So, I thought i should ask this separately with my own ideas.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You proved that the function $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, hence uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$. The expression of $f'$ you provided, plus the inequality $\log u\leqslant u$ applied to $u=x^{1/3}$, yield $0\leqslant f'(x)\leqslant3$ for every $x\geqslant1$, hence $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[1,+\infty)$. Ergo.

Comment: Ah my bad... how could i miss that... I was sure derivative is bounded on $[1,\infty)$ but  not on $[0,\infty)$... I could have used derivative test for $[1,\infty)$ and "continuous on compact set is uniform continuous" for $[0,1]$... I am highly disappointed with my negligence... Thank you  :)

Comment: Please do not be disappointed, apparently you learned something today, and any day when one learns something is a good day, don't you think?

Comment: yes it is a good day, but it was asked in the exam day before yesterday... That day was a bad day :D Thank you once again... :)

Comment: Ah. Well, that's too bad.